# How do I import sklearn on python 3.5.0 without a Type error?

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.5

I installed the prerequisites to install sklearn via this page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html and everything installed fine. However, when I attempt to import sklearn I receive the error (below).  Any ideas?

**Install:**

```
# pip3 install -U scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22
Looking in indexes: http://devpi.na-pytools.tds.local/na/dev/+simple/
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.22)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy>=0.17.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22) (0.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22) (1.18.1)
```

**Error:**

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Nov 19 2015, 10:11:12)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import fft
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/fft/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from ._basic import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/fft/_basic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy._lib.uarray import generate_multimethod, Dispatchable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/uarray.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._uarray import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_uarray/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from ._backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing python 3.6.8 with make altinstall along with virtualenv, which solved the problem.